# Adjust urgent animation's time span?

Tags: unity, launcher

Currently in Ubuntu 14.04 with Unity 7.2.0, when you receive a message from an instant messenger client (or anything else that would classify as the application needing attention), that icon in your Unity launcher will wiggle. That's all well and good, but it's useless unless you happen to be looking at the Unity bar at that point in time. As a result, the *vast* majority of notifications go missed. I can say with confidence that this frustrates a huge amount of people given the amount of users who have said this too bothers them. I'd like to adjust the length of time that the wiggle continues for. If it cannot be adjusted for a more consistent time frame (as in, it wiggles every 60 seconds indefinitely until the application gets attention), then at the very least it'd be nice to adjust it to a crazy high amount of time so it keeps wiggling until the user clicks. On countless other operating systems and distros, things like this are possible.

So with that I ask... how can I do this in Ubuntu 14.04?